# Null checking in sysout with a String message

Tags: java

Executing this:

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s=null;
        System.out.println(s==null);
        System.out.println("main" + s==null);
    }
}
```

Outputs this:

```
true 
false
```

Can you explain why the null check fails and "main" not printed?

Comment: Take a look at https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` operator has higher precedence than `==` operator, so `"main" + s==null` is evaluated as `("main" + s)==null`.

`"main" + s` will become a string `"mainnull"`, which is not `null`, and so `"main" + s==null` is false.

What you want should be `"main" + (s==null)` with parenthesis added.